# PHP to mySQL check if user exists

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, user-controls

I have a script that updates/creates user from an iOS device. Now i want to have the script also check if the user already exists in the database. I am going to restrict this to username for now, so no more than ONE unique username may exist. I have an if-statement in my PHP but i cannot get it to work - help please :).

```
    <?php

    header('Content-type: application/json');
    if($_POST) {
        $username   = $_POST['username'];
        $password   = $_POST['password'];

        if($username && $password) {

                $db_name     = 'dbname';
                $db_user     = 'dbuser';
                $db_password = 'dbpass';
                $server_url  = 'localhost';

                $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);

            $userexists = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'"); 

            /* check connection */
            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                error_log("Connect failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
                echo '{"success":0,"error_message":"' . mysqli_connect_error() . '"}';
            }

            if(mysql_num_rows($userexists) != 0) { 
                echo '{"success":0,"error_message":"Username Exist."}';
            } 

            else {

                $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
                $password = md5($password);

                $stmt->bind_param('sss', $username, $password, $email);

                    /* execute prepared statement */
                $stmt->execute();

                if ($stmt->error) {error_log("Error: " . $stmt->error); }

                $success = $stmt->affected_rows;

                    /* close statement and connection */
                $stmt->close();

                    /* close connection */
                $mysqli->close();
                error_log("Success: $success");

                        if ($success > 0) {
                        error_log("User '$username' created.");
                        echo '{"success":1}';
                        } 
                        else {
                        echo '{"success":0,"error_message":"Username Exist."}';
                        }
            }

        } 
        else {
            echo '{"success":0,"error_message":"Passwords does not match."}';
        }
    } 
    else {
        echo '{"success":0,"error_message":"Invalid Username."}';
    }
}   
else {
    echo '{"success":0,"error_message":"Invalid Data."}';
}
?>
```

Comment: you're mixing APIs, why is that? it won't work.

Comment: please elaborate... i dont really understand what your pointing at.

Comment: simple. use the same MySQL API from connection to query. nothing in between. keep it all `mysqli_` or all `mysql_`. nothing else.

Comment: In your IF statement use a comparison operator !== not an assignment operator !=.

Comment: oh, i had no idea that there was a difference... ill update it to mysqli then and see what i make of it. tnx @Fred-ii-

Comment: remember to pass db connection to all functions requiring db connection. It's not like the old `mysql_` functions, remember that ;-)

Comment: ok i tried an update but i am still not getting it to work - could you have a look please?

`$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = $username'")) 
                $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
                if($row_cnt != 0){
                    echo '{"success":0,"error_message":"Username Exist."}'
            
                }
                $result->close();
            }`

Answer (score 0):

You could `SELECT`the table before trying to insert `username`. If it already exists (= you have a result) you dont simply insert.

Better yet, use `ON DUPLICATE IGNORE` or something like that.